# Create a ttf file on iOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es, truetype

I want to create a simple ttf font within an iphone/ipad app.  The concept is that the user will draw each letter and I will create a collection to build the ttf file.
Initially, I thought I would have to export the images from the app to a font editor such as fontforge on a server, but I am now convinced that it is possible to generate a ttf file on the device.

Here is what I think needs to happen: 
1) Enable the drawing using OpenGL
2) Save the images. Is this in a vector format or as bitmap?
3) Organize the collection as a ttf file

Can someone point me in a successful direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) Enable the drawing using OpenGL

And herein lies your first misconception. OpenGL is best thought as a one way device. You put drawing commands into it, and it produces a nice picture on the screen. But OpenGL is neither a geometry nor a math library.

> 2) Save the images

For the creation of a TTF the raw data you send to OpenGL is much more useful, than anything you could read back from OpenGL.

In particular you'll have a list of strokes, which you could convert into an outline, that then can be converted into a glyph.